# Ruby eigenclass (sigleton class) created? For which?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eigenclass

Got confused on Ruby meta-programming.

So from the tutorial I learnt the following:

```
cat = "kitty"
cat.upcase  # "KITTY"
cat.poop    # undefined 'poop'

def cat.poop
  puts 'pooooooo...'
end

cat.upcase  # "KITTY"
cat.poop    # "pooooooo..."
```

So this means *poop* method is already for the *cat* object, which is of class *String*. From the famous textbook "Programming Ruby", by defining *cat.poop*, what actually happens is Ruby created an anonymous class, aka singleton or eigenclass, that is now the class of the *cat* object, then the original *String* class becomes the superclass of the newly created eigenclass.

Then this confused me. See the following code:

```
cat.poop    # "pooooooo...", it works, for sure
cat.class   # "String" | but this is NOT some other class

cat = "kate"
cat.poop    # poop not defined
```

3 questions:

1. it does not look like there is any new class was ever created when defining the *poop* method. Or maybe the it was created, but the "#class" method automatically redirected the call to the superclass' #class? Which is correct? How do we check?
2. if we define another method, say *cat.run*, then will another eigenclass created or not? What will be the class hierarchy then?
3. if *cat* is redefined to "kate", the *poop* is not found. Why? Shouldn't the *poop* be available to cat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Look at `cat.singleton_class` and `cat.singleton_methods`.
2. No.  Define a couple singleton methods on `cat` and then look at `cat.singleton_class.instance_methods` and you'll see them both there.  You can get a hint about the hierarchy with `cat.singleton_class.ancestors`.
3. You've defined `cat` to be some entirely new object now.  Why would it have the same methods?  If you say `cat = "string"` then you can call `cat.upcase`, but if you later reassign `cat = 5`, of course you can't still call `cat.upcase`.

Comment: this answers most of the questions but the class hierarchy. so just to confirm: the text is right the singleton class is still the "class" of the cat, and the "String" class is also the "class" of the cat? and the singleton class is the subclass of "String"?

Comment: Missed that part, added info about hierarchy.

Comment: @Bruce: the `Object#class` method is (intentionally) lying. It *does* not simply return the object's class pointer, instead it walks the inheritance chain until it finds the first class that is not a singleton class or an include class. Since every object has a singleton class, it would be useless if the `Object#class` method would always just return the singleton class … it would be identical to the `Object#singleton_class` method.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Every object has a singleton class however is not created until accessed. However that's an implementation detail due to optimization.

Comment: @DavidUnric: Exactly. When you look, it's there, and when you don't look, then you'll never know so it might as well be.